# Unable to open the MacBook Pro mid-2014 lid with single hand

Tags: macbook-pro

I have got a MacBook Pro with Retina display Mid-2014 model. I cannot open the lid of the device without putting one hand at the bottom and other on the lid, which was not the case few months ago. I purchased this machine last year in the month of October and only a week ago it was the Apple service center for the same issue. Folks there cleaned it and said to me that they can't loose it up any further. 
My question is, Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should be able to open the machine without using two hands by simply lifting the screen, you may find the machine lifts off a little, but it should open without two hands, if not then there is something wrong, but that doesn't meant they aren't wrong, perhaps it is not fixable without replacing a fair chunk of the machine.

Comment: I can open a part of the lid without any issues, but beyond that I need to pin it down using my second hand. Say the maximum limit to which you can open the screen is 100%, then I can go single handed till like 40% or 45%. 
Is this what you saying the machine lifts off a little? Yes, it does.

Comment: Doesn't sound right. Can you take it to an Apple Store, they tend to be a bit more understanding of customer expectations in my experience.

Comment: I have contacted Apple Support, waiting for the local Apple Service center to help me out now.

Comment: @Fennec did you've get this resolved? I've similar issue